# No install button in software centre?

Tags: installation, software-center

I can not install most of the software as not all of the software has a button to install.
is this an error? or dependency problem if so how do i fix it?

Comment: A screen shot of the problem might help us figure it out. Do you have the "Universe" repository enabled? What version of Ubuntu are you running? More detailed questions will get better answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have found the answer,
firstly navigate to system-> administration-> software sources

then go to update and at the bottom of the window their is an option to select what
type of update you want. select -normal update-
the close the window and reload.

the problem should be fixed.
-thank you for those who tried to answer it really helped.

Answer (score 3):

try to :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then, open Ubuntu Software Center again.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have examples of such software?  It might be software that has no 64-bit version, or it might not be available from the currently configured repositories (software sources) for another reason...

Comment: It wouldn't be listed at all if it wasn't available on the running architecture.

Comment: Well, I have seen this happen in Software Center once while helping somebody; not sure which Ubuntu version it was though.

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstall Software Centre by the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install software-center
```

If this doesn't help, run `software-center` from the Terminal, you should see the errors, this should point you to the more specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the button too, I found that my proxy settings were not properly set. So if you are under a proxy,

**Get this file :** https://www.dropbox.com/s/uxbi3rl2p9wmsx7/setproxy.py

Then in terminal,type in-

```
python setproxy.py <proxy ip><space><port><space><username><space><password>;
```

Now check the software center for install button.

further you may check these reference links :

[How to configure proxy authentication to work with Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77449/how-to-configure-proxy-authentication-to-work-with-ubuntu-software-center)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBtzKa-dvJg

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-software
```