# How to configure proxy authentication to work with Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: 11.10, networking, package-management, software-center, proxy

I have tried put in apt config Acquire::http::proxy, and in Network>Network proxy with and without user:password@server:port and using environment variables http_proxy and https_proxy. Nothing seems to work, not even a single proxy authentication popup window.

The only proxy configuration working is within Firefox Edit> Preferences> Advanced> Network> Connection> Settings> Manual Proxy Configuration.

- Using gconf to manually set the proxy doesn't work

Using Synaptic in previous Ubuntu versions was too simple.

Comment: Trying install IcedTea: Failed to download repository information. Check your Internet connection. Details: W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/partner/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/partner/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required

Comment: I have made a simple test to demonstrate the problem: 1) open a shell; 2) change user to root using 'sudo su'; 3) declare the proxy variable (# export http_proxy) in the shell environment; 4) open the software-center using the same shell; 5) try to install some package, it will fail; 6) using the same shell type 'wget http:/www.google.com' it will download correctly the google page using the proxy.

Comment: See my post here: http://askubuntu.com/a/707754/476968

Answer (score 13):

Go to `/etc/apt`. Create the file `apt.conf` if you don't have it there. Write the following lines there.

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@proxyserver:port/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://username:password@proxyserver:port/";
```

Save it. You are done.

Comment: storing passwords in a text file is an awful suggestion

Comment: @BЈовић i agree. what's the alternative?

Comment: @SHA1 I would write an answer if I knew :)

Comment: @BЈовић One possible alternative to not storing passwords in apt.conf: First access internet using a web browser. Enter your access credentials if required. Once connected, the proxy probably caches your access for some period. Now apt should be able to access internet, with just the proxy name and port in apt.conf. This is general should work for any other application as well.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. However I *did* have success by setting `Acquire::http::proxy` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` in the format

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://user:pass@host:port/";
```

Note, I initially followed a recommendation somewhere on the web to put this in `/etc/apt.conf`. The correct path is `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

Answer (score 1):

In the dash button, select the "Network" option. In the network configuration screen you should select "network proxy" > "manual", type your proxy data and finally "Apply to all system". If authentication is required, the login screen will appear.

Another option is to configure directly using the gconftool:

```
gconftool-2 -t string -s /system/http_proxy/host "YOUR_PROXY_ADDRESS"
gconftool-2 -t int -s /system/http_proxy/port PROXY_PORT
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /system/http_proxy/use_http_proxy true
```

I hope this help.

Comment: As I already have stated the configuration in Network>Network proxy>Manual with or without user:password is not working for proxies with authentication, it was my first option. And using gconftool command line, as suggested, haven't worked either. :(

Answer (score 0):

Well this worked - however it didn't work to just use `Acquire::http::proxy "http://host:port/"` - I had to use `Acquire::http::proxy "http://user:pass@host:port/"` even though I haven't a password on the proxy (I just did use "user and pass" to keep the syntax).

Comment: The question was about using auth (i.e. having a password)

Answer (score 0):

I had set proxy details in System → Network and applied system wide but was unable to use the Software Center (Firefox was fine).

I *do* need to enter a `username` and `password` but my actual username and password entered in that string wouldn't work, *but* when I just put in the actual words "**user:pass**" the Software Center started working!

Answer (score 0):

You need to confirm that your username or password must not contain `:` or `@` in it.
I had a similar problem and it was solved when I changed my password.

Comment: with a curiosity i want to know why its giving back a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I've applied all of the above and none of it works for me AT FIRST, even though wget, apt-get, curl, web browsing, thunderbird and suchlike have all worked perfectly for years. Only software centre didn't work.

However, I left it with a grey screen for 2-4 minutes after applying the fix to /etc/apt/apt.conf:

```
      Acquire::http::proxy "http://user:pass@host:port/"
```

and then magically it began to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a python script to set the proxy settings in Ubuntu

Assume the following setting, you need to replace at relevant places

- proxy_address 172.16.26.214
- proxy_port 3128
- proxy_username king
- proxy_password queen

I have made a video which takes you through all the steps:
[Youtube - Setting Simple and Authenticated Proxy Settings in Ubuntu 12 13 14 and above 100% Working.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBtzKa-dvJg)

Steps are Detailed here:

- First click on Dash
- In Search Box Enter "Proxy" (Without Quotes)
- Click on "Network" under Applications
- Select "Network Proxy"
- Select Manual
- Enter the proxy address and proxy port
- Apply. Enter your system password to confirm

Download the script `setproxy.py`

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/397422/setproxy.py

OR

https://copy.com/ezPIBHwKhg3Ki8f6

Let’s say you have saved the `setproxy.py` in the `Downloads` folder

- Open terminal
  Type
- cd ~/Downloads

General Command:
sudo python setproxy.py **proxy_address** **proxy_port** **proxy_username** **proxy_password**
For our example

- sudo python setproxy.py `172.16.26.214` `3128` `king` `queen`

In case of simple proxy Without authentication the command is:

- sudo python setproxy.py `172.16.26.214` `3128`

In case you have `python 3` and above run using `python2.7`
so the commands will look like

- sudo python2.7 setproxy.py `172.16.26.214` `3128`
- sudo python2.7 setproxy.py `172.16.26.214` `3128` `king` `queen`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a python program named UBPROXY . Given below are the steps to set proxy Authentication.

http://code.google.com/p/ubproxy/downloads/detail?name=ubproxy

command to use->

1.download this program.

2.open your terminal

3."cd ~/Downloads" (Presuming that your download exist in this directory)

4."chmod +x ubproxy"

5."sudo ./ubproxy"