# How to configure Software Center to work with HTTP proxy?

Tags: apt, software-center, package-management, proxy

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using the Windows installer (Wubi) yesterday. And then I tried to install Chrome, Flash player, etc., but nothing worked. Then I tried installing some random package using the Software Center (to see if it would work), and that didn't work either. Most of the times it shows updating cache but nothing happens thereafter. Sometimes I get a message saying that it failed to download repository (I don't know what this means) and telling me to check my Internet connection.

I am using my institutional LAN network with a proxy requiring authentication with a username and password. Firefox is working fine...!

I browsed the Internet for solutions and I tried many commands in the Terminal but nothing worked. Today I uninstalled and then freshly installed it again, and then the first thing I did is to ask this question here. So plz help me... give me a step by step procedure to conquer Ubuntu.

Comment: @EliahKagan: i have a automatic proxy url and i updated it in  the network proxy option and apply it for all sysytem. but still everything is same.

Comment: @Neeraj [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/118848/22949) should solve your problem. I'm hoping there is some way to do this in the Software Center or using graphical tools (and not manually editing configuration files), and that someone can post that as an answer here. Otherwise, this will probably get marked a duplicate of that or some other related question. Either way, if you need a solution now, that should work.

Comment: @EliahKagan thanks but sorry... i didnt understand wat to do... wch of those comands i should use and wer??

Comment: @Neeraj `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy` and (later) `sudo apt-get update` are the only commands in that answer. The lines that start with `Acquire::http::Proxy` are lines you add to the file that you open or create by running the first command (but you must modify them to fit your specific situation--the first half of the answer explains the meaning of everything in them, so you can do that).

Comment: now wat should i type into the text editor?

Comment: Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/77449/how-to-configure-proxy-authentication-to-work-with-ubuntu-software-center

Answer (score 2):

I set the proxy details in System > Network and applied them system wide but I was unable to use the Software Center (Firefox was fine). I read in another question here somewhere that a user did `sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf` and put in `Acquire::http::proxy "http://user:pass@proxy:port"` even though he didn't use a username and a password for the proxy and it worked for him.

I DO need to enter a username and a password, and my actual username and password entered in that string wouldn't work, BUT when I just put in the actual words `user:pass` the Software Center started working!

Answer (score 0):

Enter this command in terminal

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

Add a line to the file as below:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy"http://user:password@proxy:port";
```

for example

```
Acquire::http::Proxy"http://ravi:bnmp123@192.20.40.257:80";
```

User and password are internet user id and password. You can do it in the same way for https, ftp, etc

Comment: What if you don't have an apt.conf in /etc/apt/?

Answer (score -1):

Same problem in 14.04 - however the configuration is different (there is no 01proxy file nor commented out proxy info in the configuration), in directory

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/
```

I added a file named *40proxy* with contents:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://user:password@proxy:port";
```

Where I replaced the proxy with my proxy name and port number, this solved issue, and enabled Software Center to work (actually install packages).

Answer (score -2):

I also had the same problem... my proxy was 10.x.xxx.xxx and port xxxx and no userid and pass was required..i just turned off Airplane mode > dash>network and now everything is working fine

Comment: With Airplane mode you kill all networking connection, so *nothing* will be working anyway.