# How to set Global Proxy where the username contains an "@" character?

Tags: internet, proxy, authentication

I'm connecting Internet via proxy (with authentication) There is no problem with Firefox but I can't connect to the Internet on Software Center.

I've checked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77449/how-to-configure-proxy-authentication-to-work-with-ubuntu-software-center) topic but my username contains '@' character, so it's not working.

Comment: I can't test this myself hence the comment - what happens if you escape the @ character i.e. `http://chars\@more_chars@domain.com`