# Problem installing software from ubuntu software center and error running sudo app-get update and install commands

Tags: 12.04, updates, software-center, package-management, sudo

I am new to Ubuntu.

I am getting an error whenever I try to run `sudo apt-get update`

```
(407 Proxy authentication required)
```

Moreover, I am unable to install any software from Ubuntu software center not even using `sudo apt-get install`. I have tried every answers mentioned in the related questions here but none of them worked for me.

When I try to play any audio file I am getting following error:

```
Required plugin could not be found Python (v2.7) required to install plugins to play media files of the following type: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) decoder
```

For this when I try to run following command, getting error:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

I have been trying this since the last 2-3 days with no fruitful result.

Comment: Can you add info about your internet connection to the question. Are you behind a proxy or firewall?

Comment: i am connecting to the internet via a proxy server that needs authentication

Comment: Looks like your question has been answered a few times: [one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89437/how-to-install-packages-with-apt-get-on-a-system-connected-via-proxy), [two](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88976/407-proxy-authentication-required), [three](http://askubuntu.com/questions/77449/how-to-configure-proxy-authentication-to-work-with-ubuntu-software-center).

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to configure this on Internet dialogue.In Gnome 2 is on System > Preferences > Internet