# Install button in the software center is grayed out when trying to install .debs without an internet connection

Tags: software-center

I just installed ubuntu 11.10 from a usb stick.

After installation, none of the software which I had collected and run on 11.10 or 11.04 runs on it. Even my newly downloaded opera or chrome installations does not work.

I do not have a internet connection.

Whenever i try to install any .deb file by double clicking it,software center opens up but the install button is grayed out.

Comment: @EngelsPeralta: .deb files don't require Internet for installation.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Try installing from the command line:

```
gdebi-gtk /full/path/to/deb/file
```

Comment: You'd have to run that as root, so `gksu gdebi-gtk /path/to.deb`, or just run `sudo dpkg -i path/to/deb`

Comment: Gui version of gdebi removed from deault application set so it is impossible to install gdebi package manager without internet connection

Answer (score 2):

Gdebi package manager is removed from default application set 
and unfortunately softwarecentre also stopped offline installation support from Oneric (but install option in the menu may still work)
so you have to use command line for offline installation.

try this

```
dpkg -i  filename.deb
```

Comment: For Ubuntu 20.04 had to do `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Answer (score 1):

Run `software-center` from the Terminal, you should see the errors, this should point you to the more specific issues of your problem.

Also see:

[No install button in software centre?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6381/no-install-button-in-software-centre/222594)

[Why does clicking Install in the Software Center do nothing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78014/why-does-clicking-install-in-the-software-center-do-nothing)

[Install button in the software center is grayed out when trying to install .debs without an internet connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80562/install-button-in-the-software-center-is-grayed-out-when-trying-to-install-debs)

Answer (score 0):

The button is greyed out because a `deb` package doesn't contain all dependencies; they still need to be downloaded from the internet.
Deb packages usually only contain the files from the application itself, but not the other packages the program needs to work correctly. They're just referenced to in a text file inside the package.

You might want to give this a try:
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/12/portable-software-center-create-custom.html
You'll still have to install `python-glade2` first though.

Answer (score 0):

I know...old post (and I wrote a lot, in hopes a reader cares why), but "greyed out install and remove buttons" / no reviews / no screen caps wasn't just driving me nuts; it's been annoying a lot of people. There are numerous irrelevant answers and altruistic guesses out there, even advice to give up on Ubuntu Software Center (USC) despite comments that Synaptic can be a good way to screw up your system...because the real issue is that you need USC not to care about the network state (especially when it's clearly wrong).

The most common fix appears to be Patches/Update USC/etc, and monitoring for errors by starting USC from a terminal (I had none), but for me and many others it looks like it's Network Connections. It didn't help that I answered the installer's "which interface is your primary" question thinking it was temporary, which turned out to be permanent (forcing me to edit /etc/network/interfaces), but I installed "Wicd network manager" because Network Connections was broken anyway. After this, USC always thought I was offline (so? I should be able to remove stuff, or install downloads). While you can always use the "File" menu in USC, it's counterintuitive for it to work when the same buttons are all disabled.

*Skip the following paragraph if you never got a network connection of any sort.*

With one, you can do a simple sanity check: If you are using another network manager (like Wicd or have edited /etc/network/interfaces) see if Network Connections needs a kick. Right-click its panel icon (an "up"/"down" arrow side-by-side. Google for how to put it there if it's missing). With USC open, try choosing "auto" for whatever interface is working just fine, and viola!--USC immediately enables the "install" and "remove" buttons. If this breaks your connection, you can use "dhclient", restart networking, use the menus, or maybe just restart (I'm not writing a network setup answer, so restarting should put you back where you were).

Regardless of online or offline, once I knew it was Network Connections, I found a post from Doctoa that says to run this in a terminal:

`sudo stop network-manager`

From https://askubuntu.com/users/68386/doctoa at 
[UBUNTU's Network Connection Manger can't detect Huawei ETS2051 Modem device!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158229/ubuntus-network-connection-manger-cant-detect-huawei-ets2051-modem-device)

In case this isn't a fix, remember that the "File" menu in USC still works despite what Network Connections thinks.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Restarting the network manager helped me.

```
sudo stop network manager
sudo start network manager
```

or simply you can try

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

I use a dongle to connect to the internet. For this I use gnome-ppp. Gnome-ppp do not signals the network manager that the system is connected with the internet. This creates a problem in system application like Software center. So restarting the network manager will surely help you in this case.