# No internet connection on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, internet, connection

I recently installed ubuntu 12.04 on my old dell inspiron 1720 laptop. Everything works fine, except that it simply cannot connect to the internet. It appears that even when I plug in the ethernet cable, no internet connection can be established. Wireless does not work either.

All that I can tell you right now is that my network card is a Broadcom bcm4311. If you need any more information, I will try to answer as best as I can using the terminal. Just know that I am new to ubuntu!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help you 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx/

Comment: I figured I had to do an offline installation of the b43-fwcutter under /pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/

Unfortunately, when Ubuntu software centre opens, I simply cannot click the "install" button. For some reason it remains shaded. I can't figure out what to do next...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I found this post [link]http://askubuntu.com/questions/80562/install-button-in-the-software-center-is-grayed-out-when-trying-to-install-debs[link]

I figured it was pretty much the same problem as mine. The install button being grayed out. From what I gather, it is simply impossible for me to install this .deb file, since I still need to access the internet to do so.

Does this mean I should just forget about using ubuntu, as there is no way to make the internet connection work?