# How to get mac mini 3,1 ubuntu 12.10 hooked up to internet? compiling 802.11 Linux STA driver

Tags: installation, wireless, drivers, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

I just managed to get ubuntu 12.10 installed (couldn't get 12.04 LTS to work) on my mac mini 3,1 (early 2009) but it's not able to connect to the internet.  Mac Mini 3,1 instructions at the [mactel ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mac_mini3-1/Maverick) pages say that for the the wireless/airport to work:

> You should use the restricted driver, install from: System ->
>   Administration -> Hardware Drivers (if not shown there, install
>   package broadcom-sta). Select the Broadcom STA driver you want and
>   Activate.

I don't know what that means.  In the "system settings" and "dash home" there's nothing like "Administration" or "Hardware Drivers" despite much searching.  Googling "Broadcom STA driver" lead me to the [802.11 Linux STA driver page](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php) whose [README](http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt) page notes optimistically:

> Some distros (Ubuntu and Fedora at the least) already have a version
>   of this driver in their repositories precompiled, tested and ready to
>   go. You just use the package manager to install the proper package.
>
> Later it suggests: On Ubuntu, you will need headers and tools.  Try
>   these commands:
>
> # apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
>
> # apt-get build-dep linux

Doing both leads to error messages

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
[sudo] password for ungerb:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package build-essential
$ sudo apt-get build-dep linux
[sudo] password for ungerb:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

It then adds:

> To check to see if you have this directory do this:
>
> # ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build

When I type that in I get a nice list of directories but I'm not really sure what I'm looking for.  The README continues with some Build instructions noting:

Example:

# mkdir hybrid_wl

# cd hybrid_wl

# tar xzf /hybrid-portsrc.tar or /hybrid-portsrc-x86_64.tar.gz

I could enter those commands but am not sure what path I should use.  If you've followed along this far, may the Lord bless you and keep you.  My questions are:
1) What do those error messages mean and how do I fix them?
2) In what directory (path) should I put the driver.
3) Is there an easier way with system settings or home dash to get my wireless working without using the terminal?

EDIT: Typing in `$ lspci -nn` produces:

```
.
.
.
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 05)
.
.
.
```

Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: I've followed along and I would like to know for sure that you need the STA driver. Please edit your question to add the details learned when you run the terminal command: lspci -nn. Just include the wireless card details. Do you have your install CD handy?

Comment: Thanks for reading, @chili555.  I've edited my question.  I can easily remake my ubuntu DVD and have the Mac mini OS X install DVD.

Comment: Read the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-card-bcm43xx which includes your wireless card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device, 14e4:4328, indeed requires the STA driver. It is available on the install DVD or CD at pool > restricted > b > bcmwl. You should be able to right click the package bcmwl-kernel-source and install it with Ubuntu Software Center. Then do:

```
    sudo modprobe wl
```

Post back any errors, warnings, etc.

Comment: Definitely getting closer, @chili555.  I was able to right-click and open bcmwl in the software center where I get the Error, `Dependency is not satisfiable: dkms`  I did try to GTEM but failed...

Comment: Please try on the DVD, pool > main > d > dkms.  GTEM??

Comment: Thanks, @chili555.  Was able to follow your commands and right-click to open dkms in the software center.  In the software center the `install` button is next to "Only install this file if you trust the origin" and is greyed out...  "GTEM" stands for "google the error message" a time honored strategy.  For my greyed install button, [this Q/A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/80562/install-button-in-the-software-center-is-grayed-out-when-trying-to-install-debs) suggests  typing `sudo stop network-manager` in the terminal.  I'm inclined to do that but don't want to really mess things up...

Comment: We certainly trust its origin. You might drag and drop it to your desktop and in a terminal do: cd Desktop then do sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb. As long as you're at it, do the same to bcmwl-kernel-source: sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb.

Comment: Very cool, @chili555. Transferred files to Desktop and did both those commands at the terminal.  dkms installed without any errors.  bcmwl*.deb produced several like `ERROR: Module b43legacy does not exist in /proc/modules \n ERROR: Module ssb is in use by ssb_hcd \n ERROR: Module bcm43xx does not exist in /proc/modules ...` When I right-click on bcmwl-kernel-source and go to USC, it says "installed."  I also typed `$ sudo modprobe wl` in the terminal per 1st instructions which didn't seem to do anything.  Very grateful!  Shoulld my internet be working?

Comment: The errors are because the install seeks to remove the often competing b43, ssb, et al. They were not loaded on your system, so it complained. NP. Your wireless should be working. If not, troubleshoot iwconfig and rfkill list all.

Comment: Update: Internet started working with restart.  Much positive karma sent to @chili555

Comment: Karma much appreciated. Glad it's working. That was a lot easier than compiling from scratch, wasn't it? You will have helped some searchers,too.

Comment: One more follow up question, @chili555, if you are still following. How did you know which files on the Ubuntu install disk to use?  Is there some master directory someplace?  You'd be "teaching a man to fish" with your answer.

Comment: Two ways: many years of experience and just poking around to see what I can see. One clue was a few years ago when someone commented that it worked on the live CD but not installed. Then, I reasoned, the files must be on the CD! As to which driver your device needs, I keep lots of notes.